# Pivot Report extension

Tags: extension, civireport

Pivot Report seems like an awesome extension which I'm definitely going to explore further but I was wondering why it covers the following CiviCRM entities but *not* Contacts:

- Activity
- Case
- Contribution
- Membership
- Prospect (if Prospect extension is installed)

I appreciate the extensions developers can't get to everything but I'm just puzzled why Contacts wouldn't be prioritised over, say, Case. **Does anyone have any insights on this?** For example, having Pivot Report for Contacts would allow one to monitor month-over-month trend in contact counts broken out by different subtypes.

Comment: Speaking as an extension developer: I tend to develop what my customers need and share it. If I take that approach it would seem that the funding organization perhaps did not need contacts?

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at SearchKit to provide what you want with its new-ish funcationality of Segmentation?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of that, but I'll check it now. Thanks.